# Textarea width is going out of bootstrap modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

On button click, I am showing one bootstrap modal. Inside modal body, I have kept few buttons and one textarea. When I am setting width of buttons and textarea as 100%, it is going out of modal container. How to fix the same so that it always cover till modal container in all devices(mobile,desktop,tablet etc.)?

```css
.fdbckmodal .btn {
    outline: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    width: 100%;
}

.feedbackModal .btn-primary {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: #3296d2;
    !important;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    color: #000000;
    !important;
}

.feedbackModal .col-12 {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.feedbackModal .btn:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #007bff !important;
    border-color: #007bff !important;
}

.feedbackModal .btn:focus {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #007bff !important;
    border-color: #007bff !important;
}

.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 400px;
    padding: 15px;
}

.feedbackOthers {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog fdbckmodal">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="display:block !important; text-align:center;">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Feedback</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body feedbackModal">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <p>Sorry to know this wasn't the response you expected. Help us understand what went wrong</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">The answer is not relevant</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">The answer is wrong</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Others</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: set width to 50%

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a max width on a parent class.

```
.model-body .container {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

or also try adding the class `btn btn-block` to your html button tag

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change `container` to `container-fluid`;

```css
.fdbckmodal .btn {
    outline: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    width: 100%;
}

.feedbackModal .btn-primary {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-color: #3296d2;
    !important; /* Does nothing */
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    color: #000000;
    !important;/* Does nothing */
}

.feedbackModal .col-12 {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.feedbackModal .btn:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #007bff !important;
    border-color: #007bff !important;
}

.feedbackModal .btn:focus {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #007bff !important;
    border-color: #007bff !important;
}

.modal-body {
    position: relative;
    max-height: 400px;
    padding: 15px;
}

.feedbackOthers {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog fdbckmodal">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="display:block !important; text-align:center;">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Feedback</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body feedbackModal">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <p>Sorry to know this wasn't the response you expected. Help us understand what went wrong</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">The answer is not relevant</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">The answer is wrong</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Others</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Bootstrap 4 instead of 3? If so, your code will work as is. Here is your code with Bootstrap 4 CDN.

```css
.fdbckmodal .btn {
  outline: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.feedbackModal .btn-primary {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-color: #3296d2;
  !important;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
  color: #000000;
  !important;
}

.feedbackModal .col-12 {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.feedbackModal .btn:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #007bff !important;
  border-color: #007bff !important;
}

.feedbackModal .btn:focus {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #007bff !important;
  border-color: #007bff !important;
}

.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 400px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.feedbackOthers {
  height: 60px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog fdbckmodal">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="display:block !important; text-align:center;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Feedback</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body feedbackModal">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12">
                <p>Sorry to know this wasn't the response you expected. Help us understand what went wrong</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">The answer is not relevant</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">The answer is wrong</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Others</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If you can't use Bootstrap 4, just add the following snippet to your css:

```
.modal-content .container {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a container inside of the modal-body. The width of that container is set by bootstrap, and is dependent on the size of the display area. It does not care how big your actual modal is. So the container is wider than your modal in some cases.

The textarea and buttons are children of the container. So they grow to be 100% of the container's width, not the modal's.

You need to limit the width of your container in some way:

```
.modal-body .container {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```